# Can I allow collaborators to add themselves on GitHub?

Tags: github

I'd like to send out a URL to an external team such that anyone who clicks on it can join my private repository as a collaborator using a read-only role.

I don't want individually to add every person who needs access, nor do I want to give someone else the authority to do this.

Is there any way to do this using GitHub?

Comment: The answer will likely depend on the service. You should limit your question to asking about one or the other.

Comment: Thanks @ale. This question is now only about Github; whereas [this one](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/107522/can-collaborators-add-themselves-on-bitbucket-by-clicking-on-a-url) is about Bitbucket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only someone with admin rights to the repository can add collaborators, so there's no way for a potential collaborator to automatically add themselves via a URL.

However, you can use the GitHub API to programmatically [add collaborators](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/collaborators/#add-user-as-a-collaborator).  You can make use of the API in several ways.  Here are two possible approaches:

- Write a script to add any and all users as collaborators, either as a one-time execution or to use on-demand when you have new users to add.
- If you have access to a web server, Microsoft form, or some other method for having the user submit a request or respond to a request, write a server-side script to add any user who responds to your email/form/etc. as a collaborator.

The second approach would be more precise, as it wouldn't add users who don't want to be collaborators, but it would also require more setup.

Comment: Thanks. This will take a little bit of work; but it solves my problem.