# Can collaborators add themselves on Bitbucket by clicking on a URL?

Tags: bitbucket

I'd like to publish a URL with restricted access such that anyone who clicks on it can join as a collaborator. I don't want to individually add every person who needs access, nor do I want to give someone else the authority to do this.

My repository is private (currently on Github, though I'm willing to move it to Bitbucket).

Is there any way to do this using Bitbucket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully [the GitHub approach](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/107600/142456) will work for you, but if not, or if you *want* to switch to BitBucket, you can do something similar using the [BitBucket REST API](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/privileges-endpoint-296093145.html#privilegesEndpoint-PUTanewprivilege) and the `privileges` endpoint:

- Set up a way for the user to indicate they'd like access to the repository
- Write a script or program to call the BitBucket API and grant that user access, in this format:

  > $ curl --request PUT --user evzijst:password https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/privileges/evzijst/test/brodie --data write